# How can I encode this query string?

Tags: c#, url-encoding

I'm trying to implement a payment processor. In order to validate that the response is legitimate, I have to take the query string and append a validation key, then perform an MD5 hash and match my hashed values to theirs.

The payment processor is generating their hash based on a querystring like the following:

> trnId=10000041
>   &messageText=Duplicate+Transaction+%2D+This+transaction+has+already+been+approved
>   &trnAmount=11.20
>   &trnDate=6%2F8%2F2011+12%3A32%3A20+PM
>   &trnEmailAddress=john%2Edoe%40gmail%2Ecom
>   &avsMessage=Address+Verification+not+performed+for+this+transaction%2E
>   &ref1=aab02ccd%2D7d17%2D4d09%2Da30c%2Dad6324fe33f1

Now if I were to call `QueryString["messageText"]` I would get `"Duplicate Transaction - This transaction has already been approved"`. I can't use that, as I need the `+` and `%2D`

So to generate my string I do something like this:

```
NameValueCollection queryString = new NameValueCollection(QueryString);
queryString.Remove("hashValue");

List<string> parameters = new List<string>();
foreach(string qs in queryString.Keys)
   parameters.Add(qs + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(QueryString[qs]));

string value = string.Join("&", parameters.ToArray());
```

My resulting string:

> trnId=10000041
>   &messageText=Duplicate+Transaction+-+This+transaction+has+already+been+approved
>   &trnAmount=11.20
>   &trnDate=6%2f8%2f2011+1%3a05%3a09+PM
>   &trnEmailAddress=john.doe%40gmail.com
>   &avsMessage=Address+Verification+not+performed+for+this+transaction.
>   &ref1=aab02ccd-7d17-4d09-a30c-ad6324fe33f1

That is a little closer, but with 2 issues, the dashes and periods are not encoded, and the encoding generated lowercase instead of upper case. `%2f` instead of `%2F`.

Is there any way to fix this without doing a `string.replace`? A different method I could call that would provide the results I want?

Comment: Maybe you could just parse the query string yourself to get the components.  That way you can control when it gets decoded or encoded.

Comment: @Jeff, the only one that seems to be the exception is the trnAmount, where the decimal is not encoded. Eveyrthing else should always be encoded. This actually makes it a little easier for me because the querystrings I've posted are actually just to illustrate the different formats that get passed through. The actual response from the processor is quite large. Not something I would want to have to parse individually :P

Comment: MD5 is **not** a [secure hash](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=md5+broken) algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QueryString.ToString()` to get the full query string as one big encoded string, including all `&`, `+`, etc. If that is still different from what you expect, you can go one level deeper and grab `Request.RawUrl.Split('?')[1]` .

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code sample. There is a small issue with that, I need to remove a certain part of the querystring (the processors hash value) before I can try to calculate mine. So I copy it into a new NameValueCollection. Calling .ToString() on that just gets me "System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection"

Comment: @Brandon: `QueryString` is a special kind of NameValueCollection: It's an internal class derived from NameValueCollection, which overrides ToString. This is why `QueryString.ToString()` will "work", but `someOtherNameValueCollection.ToString()` won't. In your case, I would manually remove the hash from the querystring using string operations (some regex like `&hashValue=[^&]+($|&)`), so that you stay as close to the original encoding as possible. UrlEncoding is not unique (I can represent a dash as a dash or as %2D or as %2d), so you should not decode and then re-encode.

Answer (score 1):

Rick Strahl covers this pretty well here: [Html and Uri String Encoding without System.Web](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Feb/05/Html-and-Uri-String-Encoding-without-SystemWeb)

In that article his objective is to avoid using System.Web because of its mixed results, which is exactly the problem you are having (inconsistent results compared to the source).

If worst comes to worst, you may have to fall back to using string.Replace() or string.ToUpper() - as your strings are not enormous this shouldn't produce too much of a performance hit.